# How to horizontally center the contents of a media object in Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, flexbox, bootstrap-4, alignment

I have a modal window that displays an image with a speech bubble within a media object as follows:

```css
.profile {
  max-width: 7em;
}

.speech {
  color: #808080;
  position: relative;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  border: 1px solid #efefef;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 15px;
}

.speech::after {
  content: "";
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  display: block;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  border: 1px solid #efefef;
  border-width: 0 0 1px 1px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -8px;
  bottom: 20px;
  transform: rotateZ(-46deg);
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
}

.media img {
  margin-right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title col-12 text-center" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal Title</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="media">
          <img class="profile rounded-circle align-self-center" src="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-landing-page/img/testimonials-1.jpg">
          <p class="speech align-self-end">
            Blah blah blah.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

This code results in the image and speech bubble appear left-aligned with respect to their parent media object.

How can I make the image and speech bubble appear centered within the media object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add this rule to the CSS to center the flex items inside their container:

```
.media {
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```css
.profile {
  max-width: 7em;
}

.speech {
  color: #808080;
  position: relative;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  border: 1px solid #efefef;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 15px;
}

.speech::after {
  content: "";
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  display: block;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  border: 1px solid #efefef;
  border-width: 0 0 1px 1px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -8px;
  bottom: 20px;
  transform: rotateZ(-46deg);
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
}

.media img {
  margin-right: 30px;
}
.media {
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title col-12 text-center" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal Title</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="media">
          <img class="profile rounded-circle align-self-center" src="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-landing-page/img/testimonials-1.jpg">
          <p class="speech align-self-end">
            Blah blah blah.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```